Reference an alias variable in my SQL where clause?
I am working on a query that requires the use of flags from 2 different tables. I did a left join to get the columns but the alias cannot be used in the where clause.
Why does the ZH021ProcessedFlag work but the ImportReady flags do not read? I tried to use single quotes around the variable but there are no records outputted.
Any help around this would be appreciated!
SELECT rb.TransID, rb.TriggerInstanceID, rb.InstanceID as InstanceID
, rb.SubmissionID,EventNumber,nb.SubmissionType as SubmissionType,EventSequenceNumber
,FTE,Allocation,EventBudgetFund,EventBudgetUnit,EventBudgetDepartment
,EventBudgetObjectID,EventBudgetActivity,EventBudgetFunction,EventBudgetPercent
,nb.ZH021ProcessedFlag as ZH021ProcessedFlag
,ZH022ProcessedFlag
,nb.ImportReady as ZH21ImportReady
,rb.ImportReady as ZH22ImportReady
FROM [dbo].[EventNumberRequestBudget] rb
LEFT JOIN dbo.EventNumberRequest nb
 on nb.InstanceID = rb.InstanceID
WHERE 'ZH22ImportReady' = '0'
AND 'ZH21ImportReady' = '0'
AND ZH021ProcessedFlag = '0'
AND ZH022ProcessedFlag = '0';


I think the problem is your quote marks around the columns names. You should absolutely be able to use aliases in the entire query scope.

Formatting your query would be more helpful.  That said, take a look into CROSS APPLY

You overcomplicate things, just use the original column name in the where, like: nb.ZH021ProcessedFlag = '0' etc. But your query makes extremely little sense anyway, you use LEFT JOIN, but use nb.-columns in WHERE which turn the join into INNER JOIN

Using the aliases in your WHEFE seems pointless here, as the columns arent expression; you're just aliasing a column with a diffeyname. Also nb.ZH021ProcessedFlag as ZH021ProcessedFlag makes little sense as well; the column is already called ZH021ProcessedFlag .

Logically SELECT comes after WHERE, so the aliases are not yet available.  You can push the query into a subquery or CTE and reference the column aliases in the outer query. eg
with q as
(
SELECT 
  rb.TransID, 
  rb.TriggerInstanceID, 
  rb.InstanceID as InstanceID, 
  rb.SubmissionID, 
  EventNumber, 
  nb.SubmissionType as SubmissionType, 
  EventSequenceNumber, 
  FTE, 
  Allocation, 
  EventBudgetFund, 
  EventBudgetUnit, 
  EventBudgetDepartment, 
  EventBudgetObjectID, 
  EventBudgetActivity, 
  EventBudgetFunction, 
  EventBudgetPercent, 
  nb.ZH021ProcessedFlag as ZH021ProcessedFlag, 
  ZH022ProcessedFlag, 
  nb.ImportReady as ZH21ImportReady, 
  rb.ImportReady as ZH22ImportReady 
FROM 
  [dbo].[EventNumberRequestBudget] rb 
  LEFT JOIN dbo.EventNumberRequest nb 
     on nb.InstanceID = rb.InstanceID 
)
select *
from q
WHERE ZH21ImportReady = '0' 
  AND ZH021ProcessedFlag = '0' 
  AND ZH022ProcessedFlag = '0';


